# Error installing boot-repair on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.10

I am with problems on grub boot initializer.

When I go install the boot-repair via live CD to Ubuntu 19.10, I am getting the follow error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install boot-repair
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 boot-repair : Depends: boot-sav but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: verify that you've followed all of the instructions on this answer to use boot-repair: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/182863#182863

Comment: i'm following. but I'm with this error

Answer (score 0):

Some of the dependencies are from the universe repository. Enable it and then try again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo fix broken packages` first. It may not work though.
 I've had broken packages and this didn't work. On another PC it worked though. I really don't understand why that was.